# view state MAC validation failed

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I made one web application in asp.net. It works fine but some time it shows the error Validation of view state MAC failed. After refreshing the page all works fine. This error comes at least once in a day. Can any one please help.

Comment: Your question is like: "I've bought a car, it is nice and red. But once a day right door is not opening, why?". In other words - without any details, code samples etc. how could we help here?

Comment: @KonradKokosa Don't need your help. I found the solution. Don't be so smart when you don't know the solution. I have just posted what i found there's a problem..

Comment: "Don't be so smart when you don't know the solution." - this is not attitue that will help you getting answers here. But anyway, good luck!

Comment: @KonradKokosa Yah! If i would have known the solution then never come here to post. Don't have a time to waste..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening due to machine key is not present in the web.config file. Just download  [this application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16645/ASP-NET-machineKey-Generator) & generate machine key & put it under system.web in your web.config file.